# Login to raspberry pi running Windows IoT Core through public key authentication instead of password

Tags: ssh, putty, raspberry-pi3, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I am currently using a Raspberry Pi3 running Windows Core IoT, and I can successfully log in using PuTTY as an SSH client, but it asks for a password. I was wondering if there is a way to use an RSA public key file for authentication instead of the password.
I know this can be done in linux with the authorized_keys file in the .ssh folder and changing the configuration file to allow such login method... Is there an equivalent procedure for Widnows Core IoT?

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't been able to find anything about using keys, you could consider using **[KiTTY](http://kitty.9bis.net/)**, a PuTTY fork.

Before I switched to linux full time, I used KiTTY, because it's much more configurable, and also allows stored plaintext passwords. It's much better than PuTTY, in my opinion.